# Fixed width table -- with different width cells?

Tags: css, html-table, width

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td class="skinny">$$</td>
        <td>Four</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to make all of the tds the same width, except for the one with class 'skinny'. I can't seem to change just the skinny one though.

http://jsfiddle.net/tZHgV/

I'm trying to make the table look like this:

```
|   One   |   Two   |$$|   Four   |
```

where `one`, `two`, and `four` are the same width. **How can I change just one class of tds' width?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your CSS to this

```
.skinny {
    width: 5px;
    min-width: 5px;
}
```